# Can I specify that a generic is a value type?

Tags: swift, generics, value-type, reference-type

I know that we can essentially specify that our generics be any reference type by using `AnyObject`:

```
class Foo<T: AnyObject> {
    // ...
}
```

But is there a way to specify that our generics should only be **value** types, and not allow reference types?

Comment: I suspect the best way to handle that would be inside the method itself. The way generics work would make the proposed functionality difficult, and I am not aware of any language that allows that.

Comment: While I don't believe you can do this in a generic way at compile time, you should at least look at `isUniquelyReferenced()` to see if you can get runtime assertions of your underlying goal (which I assume is certainty that the object cannot change behind your back). I would definitely raise your use case on the devforums (https://devforums.apple.com/community/tools/languages/swift). It's a very interesting question.

Comment: The Apple-written Swift literature is extraordinarily explicit in this regard and your semantics are not constructive, @newacct

Comment: @nhgrif: "Value type" and "reference type" are informal concepts that are convenient for some literature to describe for simplified educational purposes. In reality, there is no clear distinction. I know by "value type" you mean only structs and enums. But e.g. `UnsafeMutablePointer` is a struct type that you can mutate the state it points to without mutating the struct itself. Isn't that a reference type? "Reference type" behavior can be baked into struct types, so you are not avoiding anything by excluding reference types.

Comment: @newacct “Value type” and “reference type” _are_ formal concepts that have clear distinctions on how they are handled by the compiler, stored in memory, and used by variables ___when your language specifically draws a firm distinction between the two, which Swift does___.  We all understand that these terms are also general programming terms that can mean different things in different languages.  However, in languages like C, Objective-C, & Swift they have hard, distinctive semantics.

Comment: @newacct I recommend you read over Apple's [The Swift Programming Language - Classes and Structures chapter](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html) before further conflating CS concepts with Swift constructs.  Just after the opening 4 sentences of that chapter is a nice pair of bulleted lists clearly defining all the similarities and differences between Swift's `class`es and `struct`s, and further down you'll find _Structures and Enumerations Are Value Types_ and _Classes Are Reference Types_ sections.

Comment: @newacct To answer your devil's-advocate-esque question, no, `UnsafeMutablePointer` is not a reference type— it's a value type that has a memory address as its data.  That memory address may be used in an ad-hoc fashion as a reference, but the instance of the `UnsafeMutablePointer` remains a value type.  Most importantly, that ad-hoc usage is not the normal “native” way to use Swift— `UnsafeMutablePointer` is provided primarily as a bridge to be able to use C APIs, and thus Swift must have off-to-the-side support for all the C-pointer-craziness that C can do.

Comment: "when your language specifically draws a firm distinction between the two, which Swift does" And what distinction is there, on a semantic level?

Comment: @newacct I recommend you posting a new question asking just that.  StackOverflow is a question and answer site, not a forum.

Comment: @nhgrif: I am not asking a question. I am stating categorically that there is no distinction at the language semantics level.

Answer (score 6):

```
// some code for testing    
class C { } // just a simple class as an example for a reference type
var c = C()
var d: Double = 0.9 // a value type
```

---

### Solution 1 via `extension`

```
protocol ValueType { }
extension Double : ValueType { }
extension Int : ValueType { }
// ... all value types to be added

func printT1 <T: ValueType> (input: T) {
    println("\(input) is value")
}
printT1(d) // Does work
//printT1(c) // Does not work
```

But as mentioned in the comments, it is working but not feasible, because user defined value types have to implement this protocol.

---

### Solution 2 via method signature

```
func printT <T: AnyObject> (input: T) {
    println("\(input) is reference")
}

func printT <T: Any> (input: T) {
    println("\(input) is value")
}
```

---

### Solution 3 via `assert`

Another solution could be via `assert`

```
func printT <T: Any> (input: T) {
    print("\(input) is " + ((T.self is AnyObject) ? "reference" : "value"))
}
```

---

### "Solution" 4 via `where` clauses

This would be the best solution, I think. Unfortunately, it is not possible to have

```
func printT <T: Any where T: ~AnyObject > (input: T) {
    println("\(input) is value")
}
```

or similar. Maybe it will be possible in future releases of Swift.

Comment: *"the Equatable protocol, which is meant to be for value types, whereas the Comparable protocol is meant to be for reference types"* - I don't think so. Equatable means that you can check for "equality" with `==`, and Comparable means that – additionally – there is a strict order with `<`. This is unrelated to value vs reference types. (For example, NSObject is a reference type and conforms to Equatable.)

Comment: How can one write a protocol that only value types can confirm to? We're back to the same question...

Comment: Furthermore, I can't immediately see how to make `where` clauses work for this, and I'm not sure why you've mentioned it without including an example.

Comment: And finally, the custom protocol would technically work... but it feels pretty hacky and comes with two major downfalls: user created `enum`s and `struct`s don't automatically conform to it (they'd have to be added... which pretty much means I can't really distribute in a library this code).  Moreover, nothing prevents user-created classes from conforming to the protocol and then being used.

Comment: Yes. You're right, but these were my first ideas, maybe someone wants to improve our augment the tries.

Comment: Are there any ideas about checking if the `===` operator is implemented?

Comment: `===` is defined for `AnyObject`, so presumably anything that can't use it is a value type.  Determining whether or not something can be used with `===` seems to be the same as determining whether or not it is an `AnyObject`.  I'm not sure how this is more helpful than the fact that we can use `AnyObject` to know it's a reference type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71987/discussion-between-michael-dorner-and-nhgrif).