# Check for value or reference type in Swift

Tags: swift, value-type, reference-type

How can we check if a parameter passed in a function is a value or a reference type? For example

```
func isReferenceType(toTest: Any) {
    return true // or false
}
```

As we see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28782532/1864294), we are not able to do this leveraging generics.

Comment: I haven't tried, but doesn't solution no. 2 in the link that you posted work for you?

Comment: What about `is AnyObject`?

Comment: For Swift 3 and Xcode 8 - http://stackoverflow.com/a/40538595/746347

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`AnyObject` is a protocol that any class type automatically conforms to, so you can write:

```
func isReferenceType(toTest: Any) -> Bool {
    return toTest.dynamicType is AnyObject
}

class Foo { }
struct Bar { }

isReferenceType(Foo())    // true
isReferenceType(Bar())    // false
isReferenceType("foo")    // false
isReferenceType(123)      // false
isReferenceType([1,2,3])  // false
```

Comment: Yes, but `isReferenceType("foo")` or `isReferenceType(123)` or `isReferenceType([1, 2, 3])` will also return `true` (if Foundation is imported).

Comment: Ah, the old silent cast. Checking the dynamic type instead of the value itself seems to resolve that...

Comment: Or alternatively: `func isReferenceType<T: Any>(toTest: T) -> Bool {
    return !(T.self is AnyObject)
}`

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 5**

```swift
func isReferenceType(_ toTest: Any) -> Bool {
    return type(of: toTest) is AnyClass
}
```