# Swift. Extension with hierarchy of where clauses

Tags: swift

I would like to add an extension to `Dictionary<Hashable, RangeReplaceableCollection>` which would add some functionality only for `RangeReplaceableCollection where RangeReplaceableCollection.Element is Value type`

I would like to append value a collection which is a value in the dictionary - basically from [here](https://gist.github.com/asmallteapot/5bef591b22ef59f7a27bd1d3a0a8ff8f). As it was pointed out in comments there is shorter way to do that. One can append to a dict with default value using `dict[key, default: value]` although there is a note in Dictionary documentation:

> Do not use this subscript to modify dictionary values if the dictionary’s Value type is a class. In that case, the default value and key are not written back to the dictionary after an operation.

So the naive way to implement my extension was something like this:

```
extension Dictionary 
    where Value: RangeReplaceableCollection 
         where RangeReplaceableCollection.Element is ValueType {
```

I was wondering if it is possible to achieve something like that (and if yes how?).

I have also thought about something like:
`protocol ValueRangeReplaceableCollection : RangeReplaceableCollection where RangeReplaceableCollection.Element: Int {}`
to use later as a restriction on value but I couldn't come up with a way to properly do it.

I would appreciate any thoughts on this.

EDIT: I understand that you can just use the extension from the gist and not care about value/reference types. My question is more about Swift generics.

Comment: This might be helpful as a first step: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34725431/check-for-value-or-reference-type-in-swift

Comment: Sadly it is not possible to create a type constraint for value types, there is no type that could represent all value types (unlike `AnyObject` for reference types). And you also cannot create negated type constraints, so you cannot just say where `!(RangeReplaceableCollection.Element is AnyObject)`.

Comment: The obvious solution is to declare an extension for both value and reference types without using `dict[key, default:]`.

Comment: @Marc I was thinking into that direction, even posted a duplicate question about checking ref/value types, but was proposed to ask a more specific question regarding of what I want to achieve with it.

Comment: The note about subscript refers to the case where the dictionary's `Value` type is a class. Why do you want to check if `Value.Element` is a reference type or a value type?

Comment: @MartinR to limit the extension scope to value types so the note doesn't apply. At least that was an initial question from which I started wondering if it is possible in Swift to have hierarchy of where clauses somehow.